# How to best store commands and their response code for a .NET console app?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, command-line-interface, console-application

### Description

My app takes user input (`ReadLine()`) and calls its corresponding function as a result.

At the moment, it's just a `switch` that checks for certain commands, with their response code inside `cases`, but I though I ought to separate them for cleaner code.

What's the design pattern of choice here?

### Attempted Solution

I could make an abstract *Command* class with a `commandName` field and a mandatory `Respond()` function. Then, I'd hold a *List* of *Commands*, iterate over each to check if its `commandName` matches what the user input, and call its `Respond()` function (and break the loop) if so.

### Problem

That still necessitates manually creating instances of each *Command* and adding them to the *List* that holds them.

If possible, I'd like for each *Command* to be automatically added. I wish to instruct the program to loop over every class in a *Commands/* directory and instantiate and add it on its own, or something like that.

Can I do that? If not, what's the best alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions for what you are trying to achieve:

1. Reflection. You can use reflection to find all the classes that extend the abstraction of command.

```
var type = typeof(IMyInterface);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

Then

```
// use activator to create an instance and add it to list
list.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(types[0])) // etc
```

2. Use dependency injection to create the list of types, by configuring a json or other configuration file.

This varies greatly, depending on the di framework of your choice.

Comment: Could you elaborate upon the 2nd option, or perhaps give a link to a relevant resource?